# Magento Don't Cache Alerts

Tags: magento

I had installed this extension on my Magento store: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogcache.html

It really improved the page load time for the catalog listings. The problem is alerts no longer show up.  For example if someone subscribes to get notified when a product is back in stock the "Alert successfully added" message appear on page reload..

Does anyone know how I can prevent the alerts from caching?

Here is the code from the extension:

```
    class Netresearch_CatalogCache_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
/**
 * replace this parent class by your inhereted version of th Product_View Block
 * e.g. class Netresearch_CatalogCache_Block_Product extends MyNameSpace_MyModule_Catalog_Block_Product_View
 */
{
    protected function _isCacheActive()
    {
        if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/cache_view')) {
            return false;
        }

        /* if there are any messages dont read from cache to show them */
        if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMessages(true)->count() > 0) {
            return false;
        }


        return true;
    }

    public function getCacheLifetime()
    {
        if($this->_isCacheActive())
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
/*
    protected function _loadCache()
    {
        $cache = parent::_loadCache();
        Mage::debug($cache===false? "computed":"from cache");
        return $cache;
    }
*/
    public function getCacheKey()
    {
        if(!$this->_isCacheActive()) {
            parent::getCacheKey();
        }
        $_taxCalculator = Mage::getModel('tax/calculation');
        $_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $_product = $this->getProduct();
        return 'ProductView'.
            /* Create differnet caches for ...
             * ... for different products */
            $_product->getId().'_'.
            /* ... for different stores */
            Mage::App()->getStore()->getCode().'_'.
            /* ... for different customer groups */
            $_customer->getGroupId().'_'.
      /* ADD CURRENCY CODE TO ID */
      Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode().'_'.
            /* ... for different tax classes (related to customer and product) */
            $_taxCalculator->getRate(
                $_taxCalculator
                    ->getRateRequest()
                    ->setProductClassId($_product->getTaxClassId()
                )
            ).'_'.
            '';
    }


    public function getCacheTags()
    {
        if(!$this->_isCacheActive()) {
            return parent::getCacheTags();
        }
        return array(
            Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG,
            Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG."_".$this->getProduct()->getId()
        );

    }
}
```

I asked a similar question here about the store currency and got the solution:
[Magento - Don't Cache Currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966128/magento-dont-cache-currency)

Comment: I don't know for sure, as I haven't looked at the code for this module, but it may be doing full-page caching. In which case there isn't a lot you can do if you want to continue using the module. If it is only caching the content area, I would move the 'alerts' location outside of that. Perhaps that will solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use this module but have worked on caching for Magento and used the code below to avoid system messages caching. This may work for you ? You may then try :

```
protected function _isCacheActive()
{
    if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/cache_view')) {
        return false;
    }

    /* if there are any messages dont read from cache to show them */
    if($this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml()) {
        return false;
    }


    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's checking `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')` for available messages to display, most likely newsletter module writes messages to `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')` so it needs te be checked as well

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake.  My newsletter alert does always show.  It is the "Alert Success" message which isn't getting displayed after the user clicks the "Sign Up to get notified when this is back in stock" link.

Comment: Can you give an example how to trigger that message? Eg the exact page url or maybe you have demo. Haven't faced it before. It might be set in `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')` though

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as soon as any person adds to the cart, my cache is flushing out. On further investigation, I found out that "Mage_Core_Block_Template" has default CACHE_GROUP = 'block_html' which is the parent class for the Mage_Core_Block_Product_view. Hence on create of any cart, the block_html is flushed out from the magento and this does not solve the problem.

Am I correct in the understanding or am I missing something?

Comment: I have verified this using the profiler when the query number suddenly increases to equal the UNCACHED state number when there is an addition to the CART from any other user. Using Magento Debug to verify this. Anyone else have observed this? And any solution to circumvent this problem? Seems like have to buy some module for caching but am sure whether this is covered in that too